# glDrawArrays doesn't work the sedond time in openglES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I'm calling glDrawArrays twice, the first time i see the drawing and the second time nothing is drawn.

```
static GLfloat vVertices[] = {
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    /* diagonal lines */
    /*from left bottom to right up */
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    /* from left up to right bottom */
    -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
};

glEnableVertexAttribArray( attribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer( attribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, vVertices);
glDrawArrays ( GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 5 );
glDrawArrays ( GL_LINES, 15, 2 ); // this is not drawn
```

i'm sure that i draw right, because i see the first call drawingm, but what is the problem with the second?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I understood my problem.
The second argument is the vertex index, and not the index in the array itself, so the last line should be:

```
glDrawArrays( GL_LINES, 5, 2);
```